# Highchart Zoom and X-Axis with String Array for Categories

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm adapting a highchart Graph right now. Previously, we plotted points on a graph with the associated date. The chart also had `maxZoom:14 * 24 * 3600000` allowing the user to drill down even further.

Now I'm converting the dates to Year + Q#. So now instead of September 2011, it'll show 2011 Q3 on the X-Axis.

But now I have two issues.

1) The first is it's not allowing me to zoom, since I'm passing a string array in as `categories` into the chart. I would like it to still be able to zoom, even though the X-Axis is strings. To my knowledge, zoom though uses seconds to interpolate between dates on the X-Axis.

2) The second, is that the data points on the chart when I highlight them say `Invalid date`, even though I have specified the graph to be `linear`. Is there a way I can add in an explicit value to show on highlighting here (i.e. the actual date value before it was converted to Year Quarter?)

Is there a way to solve these issues?

Relevant code:

```
plotData=[];
var month = window.countryData.scorecards[i].month - 1;
var year = window.countryData.scorecards[i].year;
categoriesQuarters.push(year + " Q" + parseInt(month/3 + 1));
plotData.push(value);  //Value is either a number or a string, depending on the graph.
....
xAxis: {
        type: 'linear',
        categories: categoriesQuarters
        },
series: [{
                name: graphData.country,
                data: plotData
            }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use labels formatter to do it.

```
xAxis: {
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
            var date = Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m', this.value);
            date = date.split('-');
            return date[0] + " Q" + parseInt(date[1]) / 3 + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JDUt2/)